# Canvas Text in Center of concentric circle

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, canvas

I am trying to place my text in center of 5 concentric circle!  Can anyone please help me!  Below is my code.  Suggest me what changes i am supposed to do to get it at the centre of circle.  Thanks.

```
       function circle(e, color, x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, clockwise) {
          if (arguments.length < 9) return alert("Not enough arguments.\nThe function \"circle\" requires 9 arguments\nYou provided only " + arguments.length + ".");
           e.beginPath();
           e.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, clockwise);
           e.strokeStyle = color;
           e.stroke();

       }

       function draw(e) {
           var deg360 = Math.PI * 2; 
           circle(e, "#00688B", 120, 120, 90, deg360, 0, deg360, true);
           e.fillStyle = '#00688B';
           e.fill();
           circle(e, "#0099CC", 120, 120, 80, deg360, 0, deg360, true);
           e.fillStyle = '#0099CC';
           e.fill();
           circle(e, "#63D1F4", 120, 120, 70, deg360, 0, deg360, true);

           e.fillStyle = '#63D1F4';
           e.fill();
           circle(e, "#05EDFF", 120, 120, 60, deg360, 0, deg360, true);
           e.fillStyle = '#05EDFF';
           e.fill();
           circle(e, "#BFEFFF", 120, 120, 50, deg360, 0, deg360, true);
           e.fillStyle = '#BFEFFF';
           e.fill();
           circle(e, "#E6E8FA", 120, 120, 40, deg360, 0, deg360, true);
           e.fillStyle = '#E6E8FA';
           e.fill();
          e.fill();
           e.fillStyle = "black"; // font color to write the text with
           e.font = radius * 0.15 + "px arial";
           e.textBaseline = "middle";
           e.textAlign = "center";
           e.fillText(num, radius, e);

           for (num = 1; num < 25; num++) {
               ang = num * Math.PI / 12;
               e.rotate(ang);
               e.translate(0, radius * 1.85);
               e.rotate(-ang);
               e.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
               e.rotate(ang);
               e.translate(0, -radius * 1.85);
               e.rotate(-ang);}}
```

Comment: In what way does your code behave differently than expected?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Example code and a demo:**

1. Move to concentric centerpoint
2. Rotate from the centerpoint
3. Move x-right to the radius
4. Unrotate (so letters are upright);
5. Draw the number.
6. Reset all transforms to default

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var e=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

draw(e,40);

function circle(e, color, x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, clockwise) {
  if (arguments.length < 9) return alert("Not enough arguments.\nThe function \"circle\" requires 9 arguments\nYou provided only " + arguments.length + ".");
  e.beginPath();
  e.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, clockwise);
  e.strokeStyle = color;
  e.stroke();
}

function draw(e,radius) {
  var deg360 = Math.PI * 2; 
  circle(e, "#00688B", 120, 120, 90, deg360, 0, deg360, true);
  e.fillStyle = '#00688B';
  e.fill();
  circle(e, "#0099CC", 120, 120, 80, deg360, 0, deg360, true);
  e.fillStyle = '#0099CC';
  e.fill();
  circle(e, "#63D1F4", 120, 120, 70, deg360, 0, deg360, true);
  e.fillStyle = '#63D1F4';
  e.fill();
  circle(e, "#05EDFF", 120, 120, 60, deg360, 0, deg360, true);
  e.fillStyle = '#05EDFF';
  e.fill();
  circle(e, "#BFEFFF", 120, 120, 50, deg360, 0, deg360, true);
  e.fillStyle = '#BFEFFF';
  e.fill();
  circle(e, "#E6E8FA", 120, 120, 40, deg360, 0, deg360, true);
  e.fillStyle = '#E6E8FA';
  e.fill();
  e.fill();
  e.fillStyle = "black"; // font color to write the text with
  e.font = radius * 0.15 + "px arial";
  e.textBaseline = "middle";
  e.textAlign = "center";
  e.fillText(0, radius, e);
  for (num = 1; num < 25; num++) {
    ang = num * Math.PI / 12;
    // translate to concentric centerpoint
    e.translate(120,120);
    // rotate from the centerpoint
    e.rotate(ang);
    // move x-right to the radius
    e.translate(radius,0);
    // unrotate (so letters are upright);
    e.rotate(-ang);
    e.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    // reset all transforms to default
    e.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. First I realized that `radius` isn't defined anywhere. Well it's defined in `circle()` but your code at the bottom would not have access to it. The scope of a function parameter is limited to the function.

Also

```
e.fillText(num, radius, e);
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but you might want to look up the documentation for `fillText()`.

```
context.fillText(text,xPos,yPos,maxWidth);
```

is correct usage.

Comment: o my bad! let me try.